# Why Hbase filters with AND leads to huge performance degrade?

Tags: hbase

Why Hbase shell filters with AND leads to huge performance degradation?

- scan ‘table’, {FILTER => “PrefixFilter(‘192.168.120.1′)”}
- 160 row(s) in 0.8840 seconds
- scan ‘table’, {FILTER => “PrefixFilter(‘192.168.120.1′) AND ColumnPrefixFilter(‘SSL’)”}
- 101 row(s) in 196.0920 seconds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scan ‘table’, {FILTER => “PrefixFilter(‘192.168.120.1′)”}
```

-Here you are using PrefixFilter.In this case, the comparisons will be held only on rowkeys of the table which is efficient than other filters.
means it will compare the "192.168.120.1" against all rowkeys of the table which is comparatively efficient.

```
scan ‘table’, {FILTER => “PrefixFilter(‘192.168.120.1′) AND ColumnPrefixFilter(‘SSL’)”}
```

-Here you are using two filters **PrefixFilter** and **ColumnPrefixFilter**.For PrefixFilter comparisons done on rowkeys of records but for ColumnPrefixFilter each column is compared with the given argument ultimately which results in the more number of comparisons that's why it increases your response time.

Answer (score 0):

Scan happens on entire table. Filters work on scanned data. So you are doing the scan twice. Using multiple filters can increase your response time. The row key design should be performed carefully, to get the frequent data

Comment: SCAN with PrefixFilter(‘192.168.120.1′) doesn't happens on entire table.

Comment: My question was: why two filters gives more latency than single one?

Comment: Yes, since its prefix of row key, only few region servers might be queried. But ColumnprefixFilter should scan for each row and each column in the table. So that can really take time. Try with two prefix filters and see the latency and then compare with prefix and column prefix.

Comment: What is the reason to scan all regions with ColumnPrefixFilter if a few already filtered by PrefixFilter?

Comment: I am not sure, if the scan knows that.